# How to fix ''mongod: command not found " error in AWS Cloud9

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, web, aws-cloud9

I want to install MongoDB in my AWS Cloud9 server. So I followed the instruction as [the Cloud9 community page says](https://community.c9.io/t/setting-up-mongodb/1717), but the command to run the MongoDB server in c9 command line i.e.,

```
 $ *./mongod* returns ./mongod: line 1: mongod: command not found.
help me to fix this.
```

I've tried searching about it on YouTube but it didn't work.

```
$ *sudo yum install -y mongodb-org*                                                                                                               
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
1062 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
No package mongodb-org available.
Error: Nothing to do

$ mkdir data

$ echo 'mongod --bind_ip=$IP --dbpath=data --nojournal --rest "$@"' > mongod

$ chmod a+x mongod

$ ./mongod

./mongod: line 1: mongod: command not found
```

We can start mongodb by running the mongod script on your project root:

command :-   `./mongod`

Answer (score 0):

From the error given below, it is apparent that the mongo repo wasn't configured in your yum package manager.

```sh
vocstartsoft:~ $ sudo yum install -y mongodb-org
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper 1062 packages excluded due to repository priority protections No package mongodb-org available. Error: Nothing to do
```

Create `/etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-4.0.repo` and write the following in it.

```
[mongodb-org-4.0]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/$releasever/mongodb-org/4.0/x86_64/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.0.asc
```

Or add the repo directly from the `.repo` file,

```sh
yum-config-manager --add-repo https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/amazon/mongodb-org.repo
```

Then run,

```sh
sudo yum install -y mongodb-org
```

**Reference**

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/

Answer (score 0):

**Either try this:** `sudo apt install mongodb-clients`

***Or consider the below process:***

`ubuntu:~/environment $`  *At the terminal you’ll see this.*

- Enter `touch mongodb-org-3.6.repo` into the terminal
- Now open the **mongodb-org-3.6.repo** file in your code editor (select it from the left-hand file menu) and paste the following into it then save the file:

  **[mongodb-org-3.6]
      name=MongoDB Repository
      baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/amazon/2013.03/mongodb-org/3.6/x86_64/
      gpgcheck=1
      enabled=1
      gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-3.6.asc**

*** Now run the following in your terminal:**

```
sudo mv mongodb-org-3.6.repo /etc/yum.repos.d
sudo yum install -y mongodb-org
```

**If the second code does not work try:**

```
sudo apt install mongodb-clients
```

- Close the **mongodb-org-3.6.repo** file and press **Close tab** when prompted
- Change directories back into root ~ by entering cd into the terminal then enter the following commands:
- “`ubuntu:~ $` “ - Terminal should look like this.

  sudo mkdir -p /data/db
  echo 'mongod --dbpath=data --nojournal' > mongod
  chmod a+x mongod
- Now test mongod with `./mongod`
- Remember, you must first enter cd to change directories into root ~ before running ./mongod
- Don't forget to shut down ./mongod with ctrl + c each time you're done working

*-if this error pops up while using command* `mongod`

```
exception in initAndListen: IllegalOperation: Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /data/db, terminating
```

**Then use the code:**

```
sudo chmod -R go+w /data/db
```

[Reference](https://github.com/nax3t/aws-cloud9-instructions)